# Groovy on computer and fuerte on Pie

Tags: ros, communication, ros-fuerte, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I know for I have find a question answered where someone was able to make two different version of ROS to communicate with each other. I can't seem to find the question again though.

My computer runs groovy and I have a Pie with Fuerte on it. I'm wondering to which extent I can make then work together as I would like to use my computer for simulation and the Pie on the robot.

If you ask I already tried to install groovy on Raspbian and it fails for libboost being a problem during the ROS install. I'll be willing to try to install groovy again or install Hydro as well if the communication between Groovy and Hydro is better.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/139686/groovy-on-computer-and-fuerte-on-pie/) by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1172 on 2014-03-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In general, the core ROS transports and message formats did not change between Fuerte and Groovy, so it should be possible to communicate between ROS versions without much trouble.

The biggest change between Fuerte and Groovy was the introduction of the catkin build system. If you want to use the same packages on both Fuerte and Groovy, you'll have to use the older rosbuild system for them; otherwise you won't be able to build them on Fuerte.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2014-03-13**:
For the older rosbuild system, do you mean, if I want to use the package on Groovy AND Fuerte at the same time ? My goal would be to have them (the Pie and my computer) connected on the network so they can exchange information and my laptop would handle most of the computationally hard parts.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-03-14**:
That's correct. If you want to use the same package on both, you'll need to use rosbuild. If you just want to use ROS over a network, it should work regardless.

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2014-03-14**:
Perfect thanks you very much !